# POSIX + BSD-extensions implementation of shuf(1)

Tags: c, shuffle, posix

I implemented GNU `shuf(1)` in C using POSIX system calls and some BSD extensions. You must compile it with `-lbsd`.

`shuf(1)` shuffles the lines of the files given as arguments or the standard input (if no argument was provided) and print it.  If the `-n NUM` option were given, prints `NUM` random lines from the files.

It first reads the files into memory in the string `buf`. Then the function `shuf()` breaks `buf` into lines by converting `\n` into `\0` and creates an array of strings `nl` where each element points to a newline in `buf`. Then, it permutates randomly the array `nl` and prints the lines in it. I think that `shuf()` is overloaded with too much computation.

The algorithm for creating growing arrays I stole from the book *The Practice of Programming*, by Brian Kernighan and Rob Pike.

I am using the [suckless coding style](https://suckless.org/coding_style/).

PS: The only option I implemented from GNU shuf(1) was `-n`.
Read the manual for your local `shuf(1)` to understand better what the command does.

````
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>

#define NLINIT 1
#define NLGROW 2

/* growing list of lines in buffer */
struct Newlines {
    size_t nval;    /* current number of values */
    size_t max;     /* allocated number of values */
    char **array;   /* array of lines */
};

static ssize_t readfile(int, char **, size_t *);
static void addline(struct Newlines *, char *);
static void shuf(char *, int);
static int getint(const char *);
static void usage(void);

/* shuf: get random line of file */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int exitval, nshuf, c, fd;
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    nshuf = 0;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'n':
            nshuf = getint(optarg);
            if (nshuf < 1)
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s: invalid number of lines", optarg);
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    exitval = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    if (argc == 0) {
        if (readfile(STDIN_FILENO, &buf, &n) == -1)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "stdin");
    } else {
        while (argc-- > 0) {
            if ((fd = open(*argv, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
                warn("%s", *argv);
                exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else {
                if (readfile(fd, &buf, &n) == -1)
                    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", *argv);
                close(fd);
            }
            argv++;
        }
    }
    shuf(buf, nshuf);

    return exitval;
}

/* appends file fd into memory in *buf, *used is the number of chars already read */
static ssize_t
readfile(int fd, char **buf, size_t *used)
{
    char tmpbuf[BUFSIZ], *tmp;
    size_t size = *used;
    ssize_t n;

    while ((n = read(fd, tmpbuf, sizeof tmpbuf)) != -0 && n != -1) {
        if (n + *used >= size) {
            size = *used + BUFSIZ + 1;

            /* overflow check */
            if (size <= *used) {
                errno = EOVERFLOW;
                return -1;
            }

            if ((tmp = realloc(*buf, size)) == NULL)
                return -1;
            *buf = tmp;
        }
        memcpy(*buf + *used, tmpbuf, n);
        (*buf)[*used + n] = '\0';
        *used += n;
    }
    if (n == -1)
        return -1;

    return size;
}

/* get nshuf random lines from buf (all lines if nshuf == 0) */
static void
shuf(char *buf, int nshuf)
{
    struct Newlines nl;
    size_t i, randn;
    char *p, *tmp;

    nl.array = NULL;
    nl.nval = 0;
    nl.max = 0;

    /* count newlines and create array of pointer to lines */
    addline(&nl, buf);
    for (p = buf; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (*p == '\n') {
            *p = '\0';
            if (*(p+1) != '\0')
                addline(&nl, p+1);
        }
    }

    /* randomly permutate lines */
    for (i = 0; i < nl.nval; i++) {
        randn = arc4random_uniform(nl.nval);

        tmp = nl.array[i];
        nl.array[i] = nl.array[randn];
        nl.array[randn] = tmp;
    }

    /* print random lines */
    for (i = 0; i < nl.nval && (nshuf == 0 || i < nshuf); i++)
        printf("%s\n", nl.array[i]);

    free(nl.array);
}

/* add a new line to the array of newlines */
static void
addline(struct Newlines *nl, char *line)
{
    char **newp;
    size_t newsize;

    if (nl->array == NULL) { /* first time */
        newsize = NLINIT;
        newp = reallocarray(NULL, newsize, sizeof *nl->array);
        if (newp == NULL)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
        nl->array = newp;
        nl->nval = 0;
        nl->max = newsize;
    } else if (nl->nval >= nl->max) { /* grow */
        newsize = NLGROW * nl->max;
        newp = reallocarray(nl->array, newsize, sizeof *nl->array);
        if (newp == NULL)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
        nl->array = newp;
        nl->max = newsize;
    }
    nl->array[nl->nval] = line;
    nl->nval++;
}

/* get a number from a string */
static int
getint(const char *s)
{
    long n;
    char *endp;

    n = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
    if (n > INT_MAX || n < INT_MIN || endp == s || *endp != '\0')
        return -1;
    return (int) n;
}

static void
usage(void)
{
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "usage: [-n nlines] shuf file...\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```
````

Comment: With `-Wextra`: `shuf.c:137:49: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I *very* strongly recommend to *always* type explicit braces, even around one-liners, e.g.

  ```
  if (newp == NULL) {
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
  }
  ```
- Every time you feel compelled to put a comment like `/* count newlines and create array of pointer to lines */`, or `/* randomly permutate lines */`, it is a strong indication that the commented piece of code wants to be a function.

  In general, avoid naked loops. A loop implements an algorithm, and hence deserves a name.
- The shuffling algorithm

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < nl.nval; i++) {
      randn = arc4random_uniform(nl.nval);

      tmp = nl.array[i];
      nl.array[i] = nl.array[randn];
      nl.array[randn] = tmp;
  }
  ```

  is biased. Some permutations are more likely than others. For details, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Na%C3%AFve_method).
- The `/* print random lines */` loop condition is very convoluted. Consider fixing `nshuf` as soon as you know the number of lines:

  ```
  if ((nshuf == 0) || (nshuf > nl.nval)) {
      nshuf = nl.nval;
  }
  ```

  Then the loop condition becomes much simpler:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < nshuf; i++)
  ```