# Implementation of GNU shuf(1) now supporting nul characters

Tags: c, shuffle, posix

Some time ago, [I implemented `shuf(1)`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240706/posix-bsd-extensions-implementation-of-shuf1), but it had an issue: [it ignored nul characters in the input](https://github.com/ibara/shuf/issues/1).

This new version tries to solve this problem (but uses the double of memory).

`shuf(1)` shuffles the lines of the files given as arguments or the standard input (if no argument was provided) and print it. If the `-n NUM` option were given, prints `NUM` random lines from the files.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef LIBBSD
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>
#include <bsd/unistd.h>
#endif

/* The buffer structure */
struct Buffer {
    char  *chars;       /* array of characters in the buffer */
    char **linebeg;     /* array of pointers to beginning of lines in chars[] */
    char **lineend;     /* array of pointers to end of lines in chars[] */
    size_t maxchars;    /* size of the array of characters */
    size_t maxlines;    /* size of the array of lines */
    size_t nchars;      /* number of characters in the buffer */
    size_t nlines;      /* number of lines in the buffer */
};

static int readfile(int fd, struct Buffer *buf);
static void getlines(struct Buffer *buf);
static void shuf(struct Buffer *buf, size_t nshuf);
static void printbuf(struct Buffer *buf, size_t nshuf);
static size_t getnshuf(const char *s);
static void usage(void);

/* sortnsearch: read a file into memory, sort it by lines and search a line */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    int fd;
    int exitval;
    size_t nshuf;
    char *filename;
    struct Buffer buf = {NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    nshuf = 0;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'n':
            nshuf = getnshuf(optarg);
            if (nshuf == 0)
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s: invalid number of lines", optarg);
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    exitval = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    filename = "stdin";
    do {
        if (*argv) {
            if (**argv == '-' && **(argv+1) == '\0') {
                fd = STDIN_FILENO;
            } else if ((fd = open(*argv, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
                warn("%s", *argv);
                exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;
                argv++;
                continue;
            }
            filename = *argv++;
        }
        if (readfile(fd, &buf) == -1) {
            warn("%s", *argv);
            exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (fd != STDIN_FILENO)
            (void)close(fd);
    } while (*argv);

    getlines(&buf);

    if (nshuf == 0 || nshuf > buf.nlines)
        nshuf = buf.nlines;

    shuf(&buf, nshuf);

    printbuf(&buf, nshuf);

    free(buf.chars);
    free(buf.linebeg);
    free(buf.lineend);

    return exitval;
}

/* read file fd into memory in buf->chars */
static int
readfile(int fd, struct Buffer *buf)
{
    char tmpbuf[BUFSIZ], *tmp;
    size_t size = buf->maxchars;
    ssize_t n;

    while ((n = read(fd, tmpbuf, sizeof tmpbuf)) != 0 && n != -1) {
        if (n + buf->nchars >= size) {
            size = buf->maxchars + sizeof tmpbuf;

            /* overflow check */
            if (size <= buf->maxchars) {
                (void)free(buf->chars);
                errc(EXIT_FAILURE, EOVERFLOW, NULL);
            }

            if ((tmp = realloc(buf->chars, size)) == NULL) {
                (void)free(buf->chars);
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
            }
            buf->chars = tmp;
            buf->maxchars = size;
        }
        memcpy(buf->chars + buf->nchars, tmpbuf, n);
        buf->nchars += n;
    }

    if (n == -1)
        return -1;

    return 1;
}

/* get beginnings end ends of lines from buf->chars into buf->linebeg and buf->lineend */
static void
getlines(struct Buffer *buf)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t size;
    char **tmp;

    if ((buf->linebeg = reallocarray(NULL, BUFSIZ, sizeof *buf->linebeg)) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
    if ((buf->lineend = reallocarray(NULL, BUFSIZ, sizeof *buf->lineend)) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
    buf->linebeg[buf->nlines++] = buf->chars;
    buf->maxlines = size = BUFSIZ;

    for (i = 0; i < buf->nchars; i++) {
        if (buf->chars[i] == '\n' || i == buf->nchars - 1) {
            if (buf->nlines + 1 >= size) {
                size = buf->maxlines << 1;

                if ((tmp = reallocarray(buf->linebeg, size, sizeof *buf->linebeg)) == NULL)
                    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
                buf->linebeg = tmp;
                if ((tmp = reallocarray(buf->lineend, size, sizeof *buf->lineend)) == NULL)
                    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
                buf->lineend = tmp;
                buf->maxlines = size;
            }
            buf->lineend[buf->nlines-1] = buf->chars+i+1;
            buf->linebeg[buf->nlines++] = buf->chars+i+1;
        }
    }
    buf->lineend[--buf->nlines] = buf->chars+i+1;
}

/* shuffle buf->linebeg and buf->lineend parallelly */
static void
shuf(struct Buffer *buf, size_t nshuf)
{
    size_t i, j;
    char *tmp;

    for (i = buf->nlines-1; i > 0 && nshuf > 0; i--, nshuf--) {
        j = arc4random_uniform(i + 1);

        tmp = buf->linebeg[i];
        buf->linebeg[i] = buf->linebeg[j];
        buf->linebeg[j] = tmp;

        tmp = buf->lineend[i];
        buf->lineend[i] = buf->lineend[j];
        buf->lineend[j] = tmp;
    }
}

/* print at most nshuf lines */
static void
printbuf(struct Buffer *buf, size_t nshuf)
{
    while (nshuf-- > 0)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf->linebeg[nshuf],
              buf->lineend[nshuf] - buf->linebeg[nshuf]);
}

/* return number from s */
static size_t
getnshuf(const char *s)
{
    size_t n;
    char *endp;

    n = strtoull(s, &endp, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || endp == s || *endp != '\0')
        return 0;

    return (size_t) n;
}

/* show usage */
static void
usage(void)
{
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "usage: shuf [-n number] [file...]\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```